# Angular 2 | Subscriping to Observables

Tags: typescript, angular, components, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to get 2 components to talk to each other by using a middelman (Service).

I have a photoshop like app, and i want a component(a window with a button) to add a layer in my 'imageView'.

they are both nested in other views so i can not use '@Output'.

Button triggers:

```
  addLayer() {
     this._broadcastService.addLayer(0);
  }
```

Receiving component:

```
  constructor(private _broadcastService:BroadcastService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription = this._broadcastService.layer$.subscribe(
      data => this.test(data))
  }
```

Broadcast service:

```
  private _layerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  layer$ = this._layerSubject.asObservable();

  addLayer(data: number) {
      this._layerSubject.next(data);
  }
```

The receiving component is not getting anything. He does not trigger, only once on startup, I want to trigger something every time i press the add layer button.

thank you !

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: the component that subscribes is not updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `BroadcastService` **once** on a common parent component like

```
   @Component({
     selector: '...',
     provide: [BroadcastService],
   })
   class AppComponent {}
```

To share the same instance with the whole application provide it at the root component which is the common parent of all your components and directives in your Angular2 application. (alternatively you can provide it at `bootstrap(AppComponent, [BroadcastService])`)

If you provide it at other components, this component and its children will get a different instance of the service.

Comment: This works ! Awesome, i did not know that your providers when down the 'component hole', thank you very much !

Comment: Angular creates a hierarchy of injectors that resemble the structure of your components. When it needs a dependency it starts looking at the current component/directive for a provider, if it doesn't find one it continues on the parent injector until it finds one.

Comment: Everytime i start the app, a subscription is fired, why is this ? and how do i prevent it from happening ?

Comment: I guess that's the intended behavior of `BehaviorSubject`. It immediately sends a value to new subscribers. If there was no `next()` call yet, it sends the `0` you passed to `new BehaviorSubject(0)`